# SQL Server Data Compare not persisting "ON DELETE SET NULL" Foreign Key Relationship

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, data-comparison

I have a feeling this is an "only on my machine" problem.  I have two SQL 2008 R2 Express databases on my box. The schema for each was created with the same scripts. The data differs.

When I use EITHER Visual Studio 2010's built-in data comparison tool OR Red Gate's SQL Data Compare v7 tool, I see the following behavior.

- A foreign key with `ON DELETE SET NULL` is dropped
- Data is inserted
- The foreign key is recreated without the `ON DELETE SET NULL` option.

Looking at the SQL Scripts generated by either tool clearly shows the problem. As far as I can tell, the rest of my FK's are fine, many of which use `ON DELETE CASCADE`.

When I ask SSMS to generate a script for the FK itself it includes the `ON DELETE SET NULL` specifier, so it's not my imagination.

How could two distinct tools fail to regenerate the correct SQL for this key? Is there a misconfiguration of SQL Server, or a limitation on the express edition?

Answer (score 1):

I've recently found a new tool [Optillect Data Compare SQL](http://optillect.com/products/datacomparesql/overview.html) that works better than others. May be you should try it..

Answer (score 0):

If you're dropping the FKs in order to not have to worry about data integrity during your load, how about disabling them instead?  That way, the definition stays in the database.

Comment: I'll see if there's a setting to that effect. I'm not writing scripts by hand in this case. Gonna tweak the question to make it clear what I'm after.